# VueJs on refresh not running axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having some problems with my VueJs app. I bought Vuexy template from ThemeForest.
So I created new component caller CountryTable.vue, it actually works but it's not working when I refresh the page, only if I login or change another page, but when I refresh it's showing that table is empty.
Here is how CountryTable looks like:

```
<template>
<div class="vx-col w-full">
<vx-card title="Countries">
<div slot="no-body" class="mt-4">

  <vs-table class="table-dark-inverted" :data="activeCountries">
    <template slot="thead">
      <vs-th sort-key="name" colspan="2">Country</vs-th>
      <vs-th sort-key="sales">Sales</vs-th>
      <vs-th sort-key="products">Products</vs-th>
      <vs-th sort-key="accessories">Accessories</vs-th>
      <vs-th sort-key="basket">Basket</vs-th>
      <vs-th sort-key="deliveries">Deliveries</vs-th>
      <vs-th sort-key="amount">Amount</vs-th>
    </template>

    <template slot-scope="{data}" class="text-center">
      <vs-tr :data="tr" :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data" :style="{animation: 'flipInX ' +  (indextr * 0.2) + 's'}">

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].name">
        <img width="30" :src="data[indextr].flag" :alt="data[indextr].name">
        </vs-td>

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].name">
          {{ data[indextr].name }}
        </vs-td>

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].sales">
          {{ data[indextr].sales }}
        </vs-td>

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].products">
          {{ data[indextr].products }}
        </vs-td>

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].accessories">
          {{ data[indextr].accessories }}
        </vs-td>
        
        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].basket">
          {{ data[indextr].basket }}
        </vs-td>

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].deliveries">
          {{ data[indextr].deliveries }}
        </vs-td>

        <vs-td :data="data[indextr].amount">
          {{ data[indextr].amount }}
        </vs-td>

      </vs-tr>
    </template>
    </vs-table>
</div>
    </vx-card>
    
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import Countries from "../../http/Countries";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      'tableList': [
        'vs-th: Component',
        'vs-tr: Component',
        'vs-td: Component',
        'thread: Slot',
        'tbody: Slot',
        'header: Slot'
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
            ...mapState({
              activeCountries: state => state.activeCountries
            })
        },

  mounted() {
      Countries.activeCountries().then(response => {
        this.$store.commit("ACTIVE_COUNTRIES", response.data.countries);
      });
  }
}

</script>
```

Countries file looks like:

```
activeCountries() {
    return Api().get("/userCountries");
  },
```

And here is API:

```
import axios from "axios";

let BaseApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/"
});

let Api = function() {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

  if (token) {
    BaseApi.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return BaseApi;
};

export default Api;
```

And in console I have error like:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

As you see I created one simple table, called function that is actually a link with axios request and mapped them.
Is mounted function a problem? I tried with created and updated but no success.

Comment: Could you post the code for `Countries.activeCountries`?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Okay, now also add `Api` :D

Comment: Okay I have updated it

Comment: Try it in the `created` hook instead of `mounted`

Comment: Already tried, it's giving the same outcome

Comment: Have you tried to use `this.$nextTick()`?

Comment: Hmm no, but I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: `Invalid attempt to spread...` must be from `...mapState`

Comment: Are you using Vue 3 and Vuex 4?

Comment: Well I'm using Vue 2 actually, but the real concern is, it's working on laravel but on vue port is not working

Answer (score 1):

Looks like mapState problem.

Try changing

```
...mapState({
    activeCountries: state => state.activeCountries
})
```

to

```
...mapState(['activeCountries'])
```

Comment: Those do exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, I tried to update some dependencies and received a lot of errors when trying to run the app. I installed the same dependencies and it works now.